# why does the <select> element get triggered twice when tapped in windows phone 8.1

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8

I have a HTML/javascript/PHP application that makes use of `<select>`s on several pages. When i run it on PC/android phone/iphone, the select element works fine. In PC, it opens the drop down. On android it opens a popup with all options and on iphone, the little window with rolling options appears down the bottom.

When i run it in a windows 8.1 phone, tapping on the select will open the options window as expected. But when i select an option, the options window will disappear and immediately reappear. So i select an option again and the window disappears for good.

This seems most likely to be a javascript bug but i cant tell for certain because i cannot debug javascript on the windows phone. So my question is, does anyone know why this might be happening? and if not, how can i debug javascript on this phone?

TL;DR version: how to debug javascript in windows phone? and why do selects in windows phone 8 browser work differently to android and iphone

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not get a select issue when using a windows phone.

However, creating a windows phone app allows you to debug and view the dom on a window phone using Microsoft Visual Studio. This is of course limited to Javascript apps however.

Comment: I think it was the particular model of windows phone i was using. No other windows phones exhibited the weird behaviour when selecting a drop down